# Replacing an entire string with one single letter in R

Tags: r, string

I have a data set in which I need to rename every data  to "KAS" for every instance of KASARAGOD in the column.  I need to replace the entire thing in that column to just "KAS" if instance is found.

`P O, PIN: 671543,KASARAGOD` to be just `KAS`

What command should I use?

Sample data:

```
G05 G06 G07 G08 G09 G10 address_2
A   A+  A+  A+  A+  A+  KUMBADAJE P O, PIN: 671551, KASARAGOD
A   B   B   B+  A   A   MALLAM P O, PIN: 671542, KASARAGOD
B+  B   B+  A+  C+  B+  KUMBADAJE P O, PIN: 671551, KASARAGOD
B+  B+  B   B+  A   A+  MOVVAR P O, PIN: 671543, KASARAGOD
B   B   B   B+  A+  A+  MOVVAR P O, PIN: 671543, KASARAGOD
A+  A+  A+  A+  A+  A+  MOVVAR P O, PIN: 671543, KASARAGOD
B+  B+  B   A   B+  A   YETHADKA P O, PIN: 671551, KASARAGOD
C   C   C   C   C   A   MOVVAR P O, PIN: 671543, KASARAGOD
A+  A+  A+  A+  A+  A+  MOVVAR P O, PIN: 671543, KASARAGOD
```

Comment: If your data set is a table, could you post the first few lines of it?

Comment: I have provided the table ,sorry for late reply ..please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought was gsub. If your data frame is called edu, try

```
edu$address_2 <- gsub(".*KASARAGOD.*", "KAS", edu$address_2)
```

This will give you

```
G05 G06 G07 G08 G09 G10 address_2
  A  A+  A+  A+  A+  A+       KAS
  A   B   B  B+   A   A       KAS
 B+   B  B+  A+  C+  B+       KAS
 B+  B+   B  B+   A  A+       KAS
  B   B   B  B+  A+  A+       KAS
 A+  A+  A+  A+  A+  A+       KAS
 B+  B+   B   A  B+   A       KAS
  C   C   C   C   C   A       KAS
 A+  A+  A+  A+  A+  A+       KAS
```

Comment: This will produce `RAN` when `(RAN)` is the requested output.

Comment: I see what you mean, but two conflicting things are requested. One without parens, and one with.

Comment: Yeah good point, not sure whether the parentheses are actually part of the string or just column delimiters.

Comment: sorry for the conflicting thing what i meant was just RAN ..i made a typing error second time ..anyways thanx for the help

Comment: x <- gsub(".*RANCHI.*", "RAN", edu) ,edu is my data set ,but i am getting x in value column and when i try printing it it gives nos in output.i dont know where am i going wrong..this code should replace every column having RANCHI in it irrespective of other characters to just RAN ..am i correct ?

Comment: You should specify the column of edu in which you want strings replaced. In case you want to do it to every column, see my latest edit.

Answer (score 2):

Sample data:

```
x <- c("(P O, PIN: 671543,RANCHI)", "(P O, PIN: 671543,BLAH)", "(P O, PIN: 67338,RANCITY)", "(P O, PIN: 671543,BBBCHI)")
```

Can try `grepl` and `ifelse`

```
x <- ifelse(grepl("RANCHI", x), "(RAN)", x)
x
## [1] "(RAN)" "(P O, PIN: 671543,BLAH)"   "(P O, PIN: 67338,RANCITY)" "(P O, PIN: 671543,BBBCHI)"
```

Or just `grep` (or `grepl`)

```
x[grep("RANCHI", x)] <- "(RAN)"
x
## [1] "(RAN)"  "(P O, PIN: 671543,BLAH)"   "(P O, PIN: 67338,RANCITY)" "(P O, PIN: 671543,BBBCHI)"
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg +1 thanks for the edit.   Your solution is very neat.

Answer (score 2):

This replaces every instance of text containing `RANCHI`, enclosed in parentheses, to just `(RAN)`.

```
x <- gsub("\\(.*RANCHI.*\\)", "\\(RAN\\)", x)
```